# Как сделать кнопку которая будет двигаться

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать кнопку которая будет двигаться

Comment: **Хахахх** @Кукушка какой смешной ник хотя стоп, у меня он такой же...

Comment: Не хотите добавить поведение кнопки, вид кнопки, описание функций ее? Желаемую анимацию, код который написали вы?

Answer (score 1):

```css
@keyframes move {
from, 
to {left: 0;top: 0;}
25% {top: 10px;}
50% {left: 10px;}
75% {top: 0;}
}

.wrapper {
  position:relative;
}
.button {
  position: absolute;
  animation: move 2s infinite ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="button">Движушаяся кнопка</button>
</div>
```